# Using a JOIN Statement in SQL is giving improper information

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, join

This is my first question on here so I will do my best to be clear.

I am trying to run a SQL statement in Microsoft SQL (I will be translating it in to php if that matters) and I am using the join statement. I will paste the exact code and try to provide an example of what is happening, and what I need to happen.

```
SELECT
  WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID,
  OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID,
  WORK_ORDER.PART_ID,
  OPERATION.SETUP_HRS,
  OPERATION.RUN,
  OPERATION.RUN_TYPE,
  OPERATION.RUN_HRS,
  WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_QTY,
  WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
  WORK_ORDER.COMMODITY_CODE
FROM
  WORK_ORDER
  JOIN OPERATION ON WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
WHERE
  OPERATION.RESOURCE_ID = '280LASERS'
  AND OPERATION.STATUS='R'
ORDER BY
  DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
  OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID;
```

The information I get back (in short) is:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+
| BASE_ID |   PART_ID   | DESIRED_QTY |    DESIRED_WANT_DATE    | COMMODITY_CODE | WORKORDER_SUB_ID | SETUP_HRS |     RUN      | RUN_TYPE | RUN_HRS |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               13 | 0.100     | 180.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.33    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               16 | 0.150     | 180.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.66    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               17 | 0.330     | 140.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.42    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               19 | 0.150     | 240.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.49    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               22 | 0.330     | 140.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.42    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               23 | 0.330     | 140.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.42    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               25 | 0.100     | 400.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.15    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               30 | 0.330     | 30.00000000  | PCS/HR   | 3.93    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               33 | 0.100     | 45.00000000  | PCS/HR   | 1.31    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |                5 | 0.100     | 48.00000000  | PCS/HR   | 1.23    |
| W146589 | 11000001722 | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |                8 | 0.100     | 40.00000000  | PCS/HR   | 1.48    |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+
```

Below is what is should return:

```
 +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+
 | BASE_ID |   PART_ID   | DESIRED_QTY |    DESIRED_WANT_DATE    | COMMODITY_CODE | WORKORDER_SUB_ID | SETUP_HRS |     RUN      | RUN_TYPE | RUN_HRS |
 +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+
 | W146589 | F3702202    | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               13 | 0.100     | 180.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.33    |
*| W146589 | F3723301    | 118.0000    | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               16 | 0.150     | 180.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.66    |
 | W146589 | F3723502    | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               17 | 0.330     | 140.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.42    |
*| W146589 | F3771901    | 118.0000    | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               19 | 0.150     | 240.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.49    |
 | W146589 | F3864701    | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               22 | 0.330     | 140.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.42    |
 | W146589 | F3864702    | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               23 | 0.330     | 140.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.42    |
 | W146589 | F3703100    | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               25 | 0.100     | 400.00000000 | PCS/HR   | 0.15    |
*| W146589 | F3864501    | 118.0000    | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               30 | 0.330     | 30.00000000  | PCS/HR   | 3.93    |
 | W146589 | 3704901-4   | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |               33 | 0.100     | 45.00000000  | PCS/HR   | 1.31    |
 | W146589 | 3704901-3   | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |                5 | 0.100     | 48.00000000  | PCS/HR   | 1.23    |
 | W146589 | 3704901-5   | 59.0000     | 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 | FLASH TECH     |                8 | 0.100     | 40.00000000  | PCS/HR   | 1.48    |
 +---------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+
```

As you can see the first query is repeating the `PART_ID` and `DESIRED_QTY` yet the `SUB_ID` is changing, which is very strange and has me pulling my hair out.

I can tell you that the `PART_ID` and `DESIRED_QTY` being repeated is from the 0 SUB_ID which is the only one with a `DESIRED_WANT_DATE`, but I need to make sure that it pulls only from Work_Orders that have a scheduled want date.

I have tried to remove the `DESIRED_WANT_DATE IS NOT NULL` statement and it did not change the output, just gave MORE Work_Orders.

I think the problem may be arising with the use of the JOIN statement but I am not sure how else to pull all the required information. I think if I was able to (`JOIN ON WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID AND WORK_ORDER.SUB_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID`) That MAY help it to pull the right information but I do not know how to manipulate the data output in SQL that way.

EDIT:

Table Examples requested:

WORK_ORDER:

```
| ROWID | TYPE |  BASE_ID   | LOT_ID | SPLIT_ID | SUB_ID |  PART_ID   | GLOBAL_RANK | DESIRED_QTY | RECEIVED_QTY |       CREATE_DATE       |    DESIRED_RLS_DATE     |    DESIRED_WANT_DATE    | CLOSE_DATE | COSTED_DATE | STATUS | COPY_FROM_SPLIT_ID | ENGINEERED_BY |     ENGINEERED_DATE     | DRAWING_ID | DRAWING_REV_NO | PRODUCT_CODE | COMMODITY_CODE | FORWARD_SCHEDULE | POSTING_CANDIDATE | MAT_GL_ACCT_ID | LAB_GL_ACCT_ID | BUR_GL_ACCT_ID | SER_GL_ACCT_ID | VARIABLE_TABLE | SCHEDULE_GROUP_ID | SCHED_START_DATE | SCHED_FINISH_DATE | COULD_FINISH_DATE | EST_MATERIAL_COST | EST_LABOR_COST | EST_BURDEN_COST | EST_SERVICE_COST | ACT_MATERIAL_COST | ACT_LABOR_COST | ACT_BURDEN_COST | ACT_SERVICE_COST | REM_MATERIAL_COST | REM_LABOR_COST | REM_BURDEN_COST | REM_SERVICE_COST | MARKED_FOR_PURGE | PRINTED_DATE | DRAWING_FILE | WAREHOUSE_ID | WIP_VAS_REQUIRED | ALLOCATED_QTY | FULFILLED_QTY | DEF_LBL_FORMAT_ID | HARD_RELEASE_DATE | USER_1 | USER_2 |      USER_3      | USER_4 | USER_5 | USER_6 | USER_7 | USER_8 | USER_9 | USER_10 | UDF_LAYOUT_ID | DBR_TYPE | DBR_PRIORITY | DBR_CODE | WBS_CODE | WBS_PROJECT | WBS_CUST_ORDER_ID | MILESTONE_SEQ_NO | MILESTONE_SUB_ID | ECN_REVISION | EDI_BLANKET_FLAG | DISPATCHED | ORIG_STAGE_REVISION_ID |     STATUS_EFF_DATE     | ALLOW_ALT_PARTS | ALLOW_UPD_FROM_MST | ALLOW_UPD_FROM_LEG | UPDATE_FROM_REF | UPDATE_USER_ID | UPDATE_ENG_MASTER | UPDATE_DATE | SITE_ID | PROD_ORDER_TYPE | PLANNER_ID | INACTIVE |

|  7888 | M    | 0006-12096 |      0 |        0 |      0 | 0006-12096 |          50 | 1000.0000   | 0.0000       | 2010-05-19 13:54:51.137 | 2010-05-19 00:00:00.000 | 2010-05-19 00:00:00.000 | NULL       | NULL        | U      | NULL               | NULL          | 2010-05-19 00:00:00.000 | B43521-02  |             03 | CONTRACT     | CHROMOLOX      | N                | Y                 | NULL           | NULL           | NULL           | NULL           | NULL           | NULL              | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | 34.66             | 26.74          | 188.64          | 290.00           | 0.00              | 0.00           | 0.00            | 0.00             | 34.66             | 26.74          | 188.64          | 290.00           | N                | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL              | N                 | NULL   | NULL   | COSMETIC LEVEL 3 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | O        | NULL         | NULL     | NULL     | N           | NULL              | NULL             | NULL             | NULL         | N                | NULL       | NULL                   | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL            | Y                  | Y                  | NULL            | NULL           | NULL              | NULL        | GAR     | NULL            | NULL       | N        |
```

OPERATION:

```
| ROWID | WORKORDER_TYPE | WORKORDER_BASE_ID | WORKORDER_LOT_ID | WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID | WORKORDER_SUB_ID | SEQUENCE_NO |   RESOURCE_ID   | SETUP_HRS |     RUN      | RUN_TYPE | LOAD_SIZE_QTY | RUN_HRS | MOVE_HRS | TRANSIT_DAYS | SERVICE_ID | SCRAP_YIELD_PCT | SCRAP_YIELD_TYPE | FIXED_SCRAP_UNITS | MINIMUM_MOVE_QTY | CALC_START_QTY | CALC_END_QTY | COMPLETED_QTY | DEVIATED_QTY | ACT_SETUP_HRS | ACT_RUN_HRS | STATUS | SETUP_COMPLETED | SERVICE_BEGIN_DATE | CLOSE_DATE | OPERATION_TYPE | DRAWING_ID | DRAWING_REV_NO | OVERRIDE_QTYS | BEGIN_TRACEABILITY | CAPACITY_USAGE_MAX | CAPACITY_USAGE_MIN | TEST_ID | SPC_QTY | SCHED_START_DATE | SCHED_FINISH_DATE | COULD_FINISH_DATE | ISDETERMINANT | SETUP_COST_PER_HR | RUN_COST_PER_HR | RUN_COST_PER_UNIT | BUR_PER_HR_SETUP | BUR_PER_HR_RUN | BUR_PER_UNIT_RUN | SERVICE_BASE_CHG | BUR_PERCENT_SETUP | BUR_PERCENT_RUN | BUR_PER_OPERATION | EST_ATL_LAB_COST | EST_ATL_BUR_COST | EST_ATL_SER_COST | REM_ATL_LAB_COST | REM_ATL_BUR_COST | REM_ATL_SER_COST | ACT_ATL_LAB_COST | ACT_ATL_BUR_COST | ACT_ATL_SER_COST | EST_TTL_MAT_COST | EST_TTL_LAB_COST | EST_TTL_BUR_COST | EST_TTL_SER_COST | REM_TTL_MAT_COST | REM_TTL_LAB_COST | REM_TTL_BUR_COST | REM_TTL_SER_COST | ACT_TTL_MAT_COST | ACT_TTL_LAB_COST | ACT_TTL_BUR_COST | ACT_TTL_SER_COST | SPLIT_ADJUSTMENT | MILESTONE_ID | SCHEDULE_TYPE | MIN_SEGMENT_SIZE | PROTECT_COST | DRAWING_FILE | DISPATCHED_QTY | SERVICE_MIN_CHG | VENDOR_ID | VENDOR_SERVICE_ID | SERVICE_PART_ID | LAST_DISP_DATE | LAST_RECV_DATE | WAREHOUSE_ID | ALLOCATED_QTY | FULFILLED_QTY | LEAST_MIN_MOVE_QTY | MAX_GAP_PREV_OP | APPLY_CALENDAR | MAX_DOWNTIME | ACCUM_DOWNTIME | RUN_QTY_PER_CYCLE | USER_1 | USER_2 | USER_3 | USER_4 | USER_5 | USER_6 | USER_7 | USER_8 | USER_9 | USER_10 | UDF_LAYOUT_ID | NUM_MEM_TO_SCHED | SERVICE_BUFFER | MILESTONE_SUB_ID | POST_MILESTONE | PROJ_MILESTONE_OP | WBS_CODE | WBS_START_DATE | WBS_END_DATE | WBS_DURATION | MILESTONE_SEQ_NO | PRD_INSP_PLAN_ID | SETUP_INSPECT_REQ | RUN_INSPECT_REQ |     STATUS_EFF_DATE     | PRED_SUB_ID | PRED_SEQ_NO | SITE_ID |

| 13451 | M              | 0006-12096        |                0 |                  0 |                0 |          10 | 280LASERS       | 0.250     | 600.00000000 | PCS/HR   | NULL          | 1.67    | NULL     | 0.000        | NULL       | 0.00            | S                | 0.0000            | NULL             | 1000.0000      | 1000.0000    | 0.0000        | 0.0000       | 0.00          | 0.00        | U      | N               | NULL               | NULL       | NULL           | NULL       | NULL           | N             | N                  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | N             | 13.95             | 13.95           | 0.000000          | 98.42            | 98.42          | 0.000000         | 0.00             | 0.000             | 0.000           | 0.00              | 26.74            | 188.64           | 0.00             | 26.74            | 188.64           | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 34.66            | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 34.66            | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.0000           | NULL         |             0 | NULL             | N            | NULL         | 0.0000         | 0.00            | NULL      | NULL              | NULL            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL               | NULL            | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | NULL             | NULL           | NULL             | N              | N                 | NULL     | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | NULL             | N                 | N               | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL        | NULL        | GAR     |
| 13452 | M              | 0006-12096        |                0 |                  0 |                0 |          20 | 800-QC          | 0.000     | 0.00000000   | HRS/PC   | NULL          | 0.00    | NULL     | 0.000        | NULL       | 0.00            | S                | 0.0000            | NULL             | 1000.0000      | 1000.0000    | 0.0000        | 0.0000       | 0.00          | 0.00        | U      | N               | NULL               | NULL       | NULL           | NULL       | NULL           | N             | N                  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | N             | 0.00              | 0.00            | 0.000000          | 0.00             | 0.00           | 0.000000         | 0.00             | 0.000             | 0.000           | 0.00              | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.0000           | NULL         |             0 | NULL             | N            | NULL         | 0.0000         | 0.00            | NULL      | NULL              | NULL            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL               | NULL            | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | NULL             | NULL           | NULL             | N              | N                 | NULL     | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | NULL             | N                 | N               | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL        | NULL        | GAR     |
| 13453 | M              | 0006-12096        |                0 |                  0 |                0 |          30 | TRANSMATL       | 0.000     | 0.00000000   | HRS/PC   | NULL          | 0.00    | NULL     | 0.000        | NULL       | 0.00            | S                | 0.0000            | NULL             | 1000.0000      | 1000.0000    | 0.0000        | 0.0000       | 0.00          | 0.00        | U      | N               | NULL               | NULL       | NULL           | NULL       | NULL           | N             | N                  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | N             | 0.00              | 0.00            | 0.000000          | 0.00             | 0.00           | 0.000000         | 0.00             | 0.000             | 0.000           | 0.00              | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.0000           | NULL         |             0 | NULL             | N            | NULL         | 0.0000         | 0.00            | V00198    | 80011             | 7014A64H01      | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL               | NULL            | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | NULL             | NULL           | NULL             | N              | N                 | NULL     | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | NULL             | N                 | N               | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL        | NULL        | GAR     |
| 13454 | M              | 0006-12096        |                0 |                  0 |                0 |          40 | Outside Service | 0.000     | 0.00000000   | DAYS/PC  | NULL          | 0.00    | NULL     | 7.000        | 80618      | 0.00            | S                | 0.0000            | NULL             | 1000.0000      | 1000.0000    | 0.0000        | 0.0000       | 0.00          | 0.00        | U      | N               | NULL               | NULL       | NULL           | NULL       | NULL           | N             | N                  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | N             | 0.00              | 0.00            | 0.290000          | 0.00             | 0.00           | 0.000000         | 0.00             | 0.000             | 0.000           | 0.00              | 0.00             | 0.00             | 290.00           | 0.00             | 0.00             | 290.00           | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.0000           | NULL         |             0 | NULL             | N            | NULL         | 0.0000         | 75.00           | V00207    | 80618             | NULL            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL               | NULL            | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | NULL             | NULL           | NULL             | N              | N                 | NULL     | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | NULL             | N                 | N               | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL        | NULL        | GAR     |
| 13455 | M              | 0006-12096        |                0 |                  0 |                0 |          50 | RECVMATL        | 0.000     | 0.00000000   | HRS/PC   | NULL          | 0.00    | NULL     | 0.000        | NULL       | 0.00            | S                | 0.0000            | NULL             | 1000.0000      | 1000.0000    | 0.0000        | 0.0000       | 0.00          | 0.00        | U      | N               | NULL               | NULL       | NULL           | NULL       | NULL           | N             | N                  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | N             | 0.00              | 0.00            | 0.000000          | 0.00             | 0.00           | 0.000000         | 0.00             | 0.000             | 0.000           | 0.00              | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.0000           | NULL         |             0 | NULL             | N            | NULL         | 0.0000         | 75.00           | NULL      | NULL              | NULL            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL               | NULL            | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | NULL             | NULL           | NULL             | N              | N                 | NULL     | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | NULL             | N                 | N               | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL        | NULL        | GAR     |
| 13456 | M              | 0006-12096        |                0 |                  0 |                0 |          60 | 800-QC          | 0.000     | 0.00000000   | HRS/PC   | NULL          | 0.00    | NULL     | 0.000        | NULL       | 0.00            | S                | 0.0000            | NULL             | 1000.0000      | 1000.0000    | 0.0000        | 0.0000       | 0.00          | 0.00        | U      | N               | NULL               | NULL       | NULL           | NULL       | NULL           | N             | N                  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | N             | 0.00              | 0.00            | 0.000000          | 0.00             | 0.00           | 0.000000         | 0.00             | 0.000             | 0.000           | 0.00              | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.0000           | NULL         |             0 | NULL             | N            | NULL         | 0.0000         | 75.00           | NULL      | NULL              | NULL            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL               | NULL            | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | NULL             | NULL           | NULL             | N              | N                 | NULL     | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | NULL             | N                 | N               | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL        | NULL        | GAR     |
| 13457 | M              | 0006-12096        |                0 |                  0 |                0 |          70 | TRANSMATL       | 0.000     | 0.00000000   | HRS/PC   | NULL          | 0.00    | NULL     | 0.000        | NULL       | 0.00            | S                | 0.0000            | NULL             | 1000.0000      | 1000.0000    | 0.0000        | 0.0000       | 0.00          | 0.00        | U      | N               | NULL               | NULL       | NULL           | NULL       | NULL           | N             | N                  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | N             | 0.00              | 0.00            | 0.000000          | 0.00             | 0.00           | 0.000000         | 0.00             | 0.000             | 0.000           | 0.00              | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.0000           | NULL         |             0 | NULL             | N            | NULL         | 0.0000         | 75.00           | NULL      | NULL              | NULL            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL               | NULL            | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | NULL             | NULL           | NULL             | N              | N                 | NULL     | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | NULL             | N                 | N               | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL        | NULL        | GAR     |
| 13458 | M              | 0006-12096        |                0 |                  0 |                0 |          80 | RECVMATL        | 0.000     | 0.00000000   | HRS/PC   | NULL          | 0.00    | NULL     | 0.000        | NULL       | 0.00            | S                | 0.0000            | NULL             | 1000.0000      | 1000.0000    | 0.0000        | 0.0000       | 0.00          | 0.00        | U      | N               | NULL               | NULL       | NULL           | NULL       | NULL           | N             | N                  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | NULL              | NULL              | N             | 0.00              | 0.00            | 0.000000          | 0.00             | 0.00           | 0.000000         | 0.00             | 0.000             | 0.000           | 0.00              | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.00             | 0.0000           | NULL         |             0 | NULL             | N            | NULL         | 0.0000         | 75.00           | NULL      | NULL              | NULL            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | 0.0000        | 0.0000        | NULL               | NULL            | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL          | NULL             | NULL           | NULL             | N              | N                 | NULL     | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL             | NULL             | N                 | N               | 2013-07-29 00:00:00.000 | NULL        | NULL        | GAR     |
```

Comment: Can you also edit above to post a sample of the rows from the two tables which are producing the output you've already posted? That would help to understand the relationship between these two tables.  Also, I'm unsure what you mean by _I do not know how to manipulate the data output in SQL that way_.  It is valid to use multiple matching conditions in the join's `ON`, if that is what is needed to express the relationship.

Comment: And welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way.

Comment: It sounds to me like "INNER JOIN ON WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID AND WORK_ORDER.SUB_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID" is exactly what you want... so why don't you try it?

Comment: you're not grouping and you have no aggregate functions, so you're getting exactly what you asked for - all records which fulfill the `where` requirements.

Comment: The only thing you are `JOINing` on is the `BASE_ID` and it appears to not be enough to differentiate the `PART_ID` lines. Thus, you are `JOINing` each `PART_ID` with that `BASE_ID` in your `WORK_ORDER` table to the `SUB_IDs` in your `OPERATION` table.

Comment: It would help if you would post the table structure for `WORK_ORDER` and `OPERATION` to see what columns are `JOINable`. You likely need to add conditions to your `JOIN` to have the desired result.

Comment: I was able to add in snip-its of the tables but it isn't the best example. I was short on characters... What I am trying to accomplish is a report that pulls from both tables. I want to pull the task from the Operation tables as they correlate to the Work Order legs in the Work Order table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full SQL :

```
Declare @BaseId as Varchar(10) = 'W146589'

SELECT
        WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID          
    ,   WORK_ORDER.PART_ID  
    ,   WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_QTY  
    ,   WO.DESIRED_WANT_DATE 
    ,   WO.COMMODITY_CODE   
    ,   OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID         
    ,   OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID      
    ,   OPERATION.SETUP_HRS
    ,   OPERATION.RUN           
    ,   OPERATION.RUN_TYPE
    ,   OPERATION.RUN_HRS

FROM
        WORK_ORDER
JOIN            
        WORK_ORDER  WO  
    ON  WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID      =   WO.BASE_ID
    AND WO.SUB_ID = 0 
JOIN    OPERATION 
    ON  WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID      =   @BaseId
    AND WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID      =   OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
    AND WORK_ORDER.SUB_ID       =   OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID  

WHERE   OPERATION.Sequence_No   =   ( 
                                    SELECT  TOP 1 Oper.Sequence_No
                                    FROM    OPERATION Oper      
                                    WHERE   Oper.WorkOrder_Base_Id  =   WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID      
                                        AND Oper.Resource_ID        =   OPERATION.Resource_ID
                                        AND Oper.Resource_ID        =   '280LASERS'       
                                        AND Oper.Status             =   'R'                                     
                                        AND Oper.Status             =   OPERATION.Status
                                    )
ORDER 
    BY
        OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID  
    ,   WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID          
    ,   WORK_ORDER.PART_ID      
    ,   DESIRED_WANT_DATE

;
```

Comment: Juan, this looks great man, thank you so much. I have 2 questions for ya. As, I will be using this code in PHP to print the information to the page, can I have this code pull all work_orders that meet the criteria (Status='R' and/or have a certain desired want date)? I feel that by looking at the code this should be accomplished by simply removing the 2 lines that reference @BaseId, is this the case?

Comment: Yes Justin.   As written, it narrows the search to a single workcenter :  280LASERS, and to a single Base_ID :  'W146589'.   You can change those, or remove those, or whatever combination you need.  You can also filter by Dates, by adding the parameter, then using it in the Where clause ( additionally, outside of the test for Sequence_No ).

Comment: Hey Juan, One last thing, and this is minor but, when I run this query in SQL it takes 13:45 to return data. However, when I just run a simple SELECT * FROM WORK_ORDER it takes 0:01 seconds, why do you think it takes so long and is there anyway to speed it up? I just know when this starts running in PHP its going to be a hassle for most.

Comment: Probably an index thing.   Can you show me the DDL for all the indexes on those tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Justin,

It appears that you are writing a WorkStation_Next_Available_Task rpt.

You want a list of Work Orders, and Operations Sequence where the next incompleted operation is Status = R ( Ready ) and the WorkCenter is '280-Lasers'.    In other  words, all work orders where the next job step is takes place on workcenter '280-Lasers', sorted by need date ascending, then operations sequence #.

If that is right, then your SQL needs a sub-select so that you get ONLY those jobs where the NEXT AVAILABLE operation step is ready and which crosses workcenter '280-Lasers'.   But it appears you are getting ALL operations from any job that has ANY ready operation that crosses workcenter '280-Lasers'

To fix that, add a subselect, following the where test that evaluates Operations Status = 'R'

It should look like this :

```
AND   OPERATIONS.Seq_Num = ( 
                    Select  TOP 1 Oper.Seq_Num
                    FROM    OPERATION Oper 
                    Where   Oper.WorkOerder_Base_Id = WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID 
                        AND     Oper.Resource_ID = '280_LASERS'
                        AND     Oper.Status = 'R'
                )
```

Separately, remove the test for

```
Oper.Resource_ID = '280_LASERS'

AND     Oper.Status = 'R'
```

from your existing Where condition.  Let the subselect do that.

Full sql :

```
SELECT
  WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID,
  OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID,
  WORK_ORDER.PART_ID,
  OPERATION.SETUP_HRS,
  OPERATION.RUN,
  OPERATION.RUN_TYPE,
  OPERATION.RUN_HRS,
  WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_QTY,
  WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
  WORK_ORDER.COMMODITY_CODE
FROM
  dbo.WORK_ORDER
  JOIN dbo.OPERATION ON WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
WHERE
  OPERATION.Sequence_No = ( 


                    Select  TOP 1 Oper.Sequence_No
                    FROM    OPERATION Oper      
                    Where   Oper.WorkOrder_Base_Id =     WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID         
                        AND Oper.Resource_ID = '280LASERS'        
                        AND OPERATION.STATUS='R'
                    )
ORDER BY
  DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
  OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID;
```

Comment: Justin, I've added the full SQL into the answer block above.   I imported your data samples to my SQL Server at home and confirmed the SQL.   The data samples in your Work_Order and Operations tables are not the same data as in your examples above, so I can't absolutely proof the results, but have taken it as far as I can on those 2 data sources.  Give it a run and if questions still exist...write back.    I worked in Mfg for a while so this is a very familiar problem.   A fun one too /:-)

Comment: oops...found a typo      in the subselect, the AND OPERATION.STATUS= 'R'     should be   AND Oper.STATUS = 'R'

Comment: Juan, thank you so much for your help I feel that we are getting much closer to a solution.
Juan I would like to be able to past the table info for you. I have one that has more information and would allow me to better outline the parts where I am needing help but they greatly exceed the acceptable char. count (Mostly due to formatting for readability). Is there any way for me to post this information even if it must be elsewhere?

I apologize for the trouble but I am new to forum usage and not familiar with the tricks of the trade.